# iOS 8+ Core Data Faults When Resuming App From Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

This issue only occurs in iOS 8 or higher. I have a core data managed object that I'm assigning to the property of a `UIViewController`. Whenever I leave the app and resume it from the background, the managed object faults. Whenever I attempt to access a property on the object, the fault does not fire and all of the data returns `nil`.

I set an observer for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` to examine the `selectedObject`, and at that point in the code execution the object has not faulted yet. It only faults following the app entering the foreground. Does anyone have any idea what could be happening here?

### Edit #1:

Here's more of the relevant files. Note these have been simplified and variable names changed to protect the original code:

**myAppDelegate.h**

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

**myAppDelegate.m**

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    // This code only gets hit the first time the app tries to access the context.
    // After that (including when the app resumes from the background), the one stored in __managedObjectContext is returned.
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

**DetailView.h**

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) MyObject *selectedObject;
```

**DetailView.m**

```
@synthesize selectedObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(willEnterForeground)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didBecomeActive)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];

- (void)willEnterForeground
{
    NSLog(@"App will enter foreground."); // breakpoint here
}

- (void)didBecomeActive
{
    NSLog(@"App became active."); // breakpoint here
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((myAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(selected == YES)", nil];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    selectedObject = (MyObject*)[[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *link = [selectedObject link]; // breakpoint here
}
```

When I hit the breakpoints in `willEnterForeground` and `didBecomeActive` I check the `selectedObject`:

> MyObject: 0x7fa801c80bc0 (entity: MyObject; id: 0xd000000020940002 x-coredata://9775DE4D-2312-4684-904B-613302AC2B19/MyObject/p2085 ; data: { link = "http://www.example.com" }

I also check `[selectedProperty managedObjectContext]` and the `[myAppDelegate managedObjectContext]`, both give me the following:

> NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7fa7fbc96c90

Now if I click the button that is bound to `buttonPressed:` and re-check everything, `[myAppDelegate managedObjectContext]` still gives me the same output above, but `[selectedObject managedObjectContext]` is `nil` and examining the object gives the following:

> MyObject: 0x7fa801c80bc0 (entity: MyObject; id: 0xd000000020940002 x-coredata://9775DE4D-2312-4684-904B-613302AC2B19/MyObject/p2085 ; data: fault)

And when `[selectedObject link]` is accessed it returns `nil`. To the best of my knowledge, none of my code is being run following the `willEnterForeground` and `didBecomeActive` methods when the app resumes from the background.

Comment: ARC was introduced in 2011!

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833305/accessing-a-core-data-nsmanagedobject-after-resuming-from-background-crashes-the

Comment: I have, but none of the scenarios seemed to fit. I'm not manually refreshing the context anywhere and I'm not using the MagicalRecord lib. It seems strange to me too that this is only occurring in iOS 8 and higher. iOS 7 and below do not have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be some of my code was being executed inadvertently. The main view of my app has a MKMapView displayed. For some reason on iOS 8+ when the app resumed from the background, the `regionDidChangeAnimated` event was being fired even though the region had not changed and this view wasn't even being displayed.

There was code running for `regionDidChangeAnimated` that reloads the map data from a web service and stores it in core data (hence why my core data was perma-faulted). This was only meant to be fired when the map was changed via user interaction or code I explicitly wrote to change the map region.

My guess is the map is doing some caching and when it resumes from the background it resets the region which is causing the event to fire inadvertently. To work around this, I added a check to ensure the view is currently displayed.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.navigationController.visibleViewController != self)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Update map logic here...
```

It seems strange to me that there wouldn't be some check in place to prevent this event from firing when retrieving from a cached state, but c'est la vie.

Answer (score 2):

The `managedObjectContext` of a `NSManagedObject` is not guaranteed. If you need it, you have to also store a strong reference to the context.

If upon resume your data has become stale (you cannot access the stored object's properties), re-fetch in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: The managedObjectContext on the AppDelegate is a strong reference. Are you saying I need a strong reference on the UIViewController as well?

Comment: Not really, this is just common practice because some developers think it is bad practice to reference the app delegate in a class (reduced modularity). But if your app delegate returns nil for the context, set a breakpoint there and investigate.

Comment: The app delegate isn't returning nil, its returning the same context at the same memory address. Only the [selectedObject managedObjectContext] is returning nil.

Comment: But why do you care? You have the context so why do you want to get it from the selected object? As stated in my answer, it is not guaranteed.

Comment: I don't need the context, I need the object's fault to fire when I access its data. I only mentioned the context being nil in case it was symptomatic of the root issue.

Comment: Are you running the code you quoted with the context from the app delegate? Immediately after this, the object should be in usable state.

Comment: No, the code is being run in a UIViewController later in the app.

Comment: You should show the code that is not working, not any unrelated code.

Comment: It isn't unrelated, it's the only relevant piece of code I can provide. I fetch the data and store it in selectedObject. I hit the Home button on the iOS device and then resume the app. When I resume, the selectedObject variable's data has faulted and is not retrieved when I attempt to access it.

Comment: Check if you can access the properties in `viewWillAppear`, re-fetch if not.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is not fired when resuming from the background, that's why I set an observer on `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. The data is still accessible at this point in the code; it is only after entering the foreground that the data faults and becomes irretrievable.

Comment: Sorry, on my device it *does* fire `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` when resuming from the background.

Answer (score 0):

Reading comments in another answer, I see this comment from the OP:

> The app delegate isn't returning nil, its returning the same context at the same memory address. Only the [selectedObject managedObjectContext] is returning nil.

If it's true, it means that your app, at some point, is updating its `[AppDelegate context]` property (probably allocating a new one, for this you should show your `AppDelegate` code). 
The previous context is deallocated (since NSManagedObject doesn't retain its own context), the object points to a non valid / nil reference and for this reason is unable to fire the fault.

Comment: The problem seems to be where to refresh it, not how or why it is necessary.

Comment: "Searching where" is the step after "knowing why"...The first position to search to is AppDelegate

Comment: I've edited the question to include all of the relevant code I can think of and a little more details about the process I'm going through. It doesn't seem like the context is being reallocated, but how would I be able to tell? I only ever access the context using the property on the app delegate.